# Replicate elements from an array into a different array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, cell, bsxfun

In Matlab I have an array `"latencies"` (size 1x11) and a cell array `"Latencies_ms"` (size 1x298). `latencies` is a smaller part of `Latencies_ms`, i.e. the values in `latencies` exist within `Latencies_ms`. I want to be able to find each value in `latencies` inside `Latencies_ms` and then add `1000` to that value and repeat this 8 times inside `Latencies_ms`.

So for example,

```
latencies = [62626  176578  284690  397708  503278  614724  722466]
```

and (a small sample of Latencies_ms)

```
Latencies_ms = {3458, 62626, 123456, 7891011, 121341, 222112, 176578}
```

I want the output to be

```
out = {3458, 62626, 63626,  64626,  65626,  66626,  67626,  68626,  69626,  70626, 123456, 7891011, 121341, 222112, 176578, 177578, 178578, 179578, 180578, 181578, 182578, 183578, 184578,}
```

As a starting point I decided to see if I could just replicate each element without adding 1000 and I have used the following code with `repmat`:

```
out = arrayfun( @(x,b)[x; repmat({latencies},8,1)],... 
Latencies_ms, ismember(cell2mat(Latencies_ms),latencies), 'uni', 0 );
out = vertcat(out4{:});
```

where I match the elements of latencies with Latencies_ms and then use `repmat` however using it like this inserts the entire `latencies` array at the correct locations rather than repeating the elements.

Then if I try using a for-loop like this:

```
for i=1:length(latencies)
   out = arrayfun( @(x,b)[x; repmat({latencies(i)},8,1)],... 
   Latencies_ms, ismember(cell2mat(Latencies_ms),latencies), 'uni', 0 );
   out = vertcat(out4{:});
end
```

it repeats just the last element of latencies so its correctly doing the replication but not of the correct elements.

I'm not too proficient with `arrayfun` and I think its whole point is to avoid using for-loops so I'm sure this isn't the correct way anyway but I feel like I'm almost there... Does anyone know what I am missing???

I don't have to use arrayfun, I tried to do this using for-loops but it got a bit messy but there isn't a restriction on using just arrayfun I just want to get to the correct output!

Comment: `arrayfun` is really just a "loop in disguise", you might find it easier to replace it with a full loop so what's happening is clearer to you, then include the additional operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a loopless way:

```
ind = ismember([Latencies_ms{:}] , latencies);      %Indices of the values to be repeated
repvals = bsxfun(@plus, repmat([Latencies_ms{ind}], 9, 1).', 0:1000:8000); %Rep+increment
out = Latencies_ms;
out(ind) = mat2cell(repvals, ones(1, sum(ind)), 9); %Replacing with repeated+inc elements
out = [out{:}]; %Converting to comma-separated list and then concatenating horizontally
```

The factor `9` in 2nd and 4th line is there since the matched element is to be kept once and repeated 8 times with increments (total = 9 times). The second line can be written with implicit expansion in ≥ R2016b as:

```
repvals  = repmat([Latencies_ms{ind}], 9, 1).' + (0:1000:8000);
```

`arrayfun` is a one-line wrapper for a loop. It is *still* a loop. But loops have been significantly improved in newer versions (starting from R2015b) and sometimes their performance even surpass the vectorised code. So no need to avoid an easy loop that you can understand for complicated vectorisation unless it's a bottle-neck.

Comment: Thank you! I am working on recreating this through loops but haven't succeeded so far but this solution works for now for what I need to do!

Comment: Thanks so much for this once again I have played around with it a bit more and modified it so that I am able to include it in a loop as I need and I understand much better how the whole bsxfun and arrayfun is working!

Comment: @MaheenSiddiqui You essentially needed `bsxfun` and `arrayfun`? I don't understand why

Comment: For one bit I need to do operations in cells so its easier to use bsxfun and I didn't fully understand how it was working but now I do